# On the notion of Cech-complete

Tags: general-topology, baire-category

I read [this old question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24424/products-of-baire-spaces), and in particular I was interested in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/63937).

Ostap says that for the concept of Cech-complete a generalization of the Baire's theorem holds, but he didn't say that a Cech-complete space is a Baire space, is this true?
Furthermore is this theorem also a generalization of the theorem "a pseudocompact completely regular is a Baire space" (this is the exercise XI.10.10 of Dugundji)?

Comment: No to the last one I think, as a pseudocompact completely regular space need not be Cech-complete. So its being Baire is not always a consequence of it being Cech-complete. For both being Baire does follow from pseudocompleteness; see my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Cech-complete space is indeed a Baire space (see Engelking General Topology ,Corr. 3.9.4) and any product of Cech-complete spaces is Baire (but not always Cech-complete). Something better holds for pseudocomplete spaces, introduced by Oxtoby (see [this more recent paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864113003891) for more info): they are Baire and all their products are still pseudocomplete (so still Baire). Pseudocompact completely regular spaces are pseudocomplete.

So I'd say that going via pseudocompleteness instead of Cech-completeness gives us a better common strengthening of Baire : it's a class of spaces that includes all completely metrisable spaces and all locally compact Hausdorff spaces, even all Cech-complete spaces,  and pseudocompact completely regular spaces as well. All its members are Baire and it's closed under all products. And the Sorgenfrey line is pseudocomplete but not Cech-complete, as I explain in the comments.

But still, as you know, there is a product of two Baire spaces that is not Baire. But it does not happen for the nice and common classes of Baire spaces that happen to be pseudocomplete.

Comment: Thank you very much Henno, yuor help is very appreciated, but there is one more thing i would like to ask to you: the Sorgenfrey line is Cech- complete? And is pseudocomplete?

Comment: @G.Ottaviano It is pseudocomplete, but not Cech-complete (I believe). A reference for the former: https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0166864198000959/1-s2.0-S0166864198000959-main.pdf?_tid=e74666e6-c19c-4368-b22d-fb0e0d07e55d&acdnat=1522275729_d7cc5f9d8a8c0388bc3831d10da7395c

Comment: @G.Ottaviano see problems 271/272 in Tkachuk $C_p(X)$ problem book (topology and function spaces): If $X$ is Cech-complete and Lindelöf, $X^2$ is Lindelöf (even $X^\omega$ is) so the Sorgenfrey line cannot be Cech-complete.

Comment: Nice answer, I didn't know about pseudocomplete spaces. I have found a small issue with the proof of productivity of pseudocomplete spaces: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3518983/pseudocomplete-spaces.