# Pseudocomplete spaces

Tags: general-topology, baire-category

It is well-known that both locally compact Hausdorff spaces and completely metrizable spaces are Baire (i.e. satisfiy the Baire category theorem). A common generalization of both classes while still being Baire is the class of Čech-complete spaces. A finite product of Baire spaces does not have to be Baire; any product of Čech-complete spaces is Baire but not necessarily Čech-complete.

In 1960 Oxtoby defined the class of *pseudocomplete* spaces. This is a nice property that captures the idea of the proof of the Baire category theorem. It is easy to see that every Čech-complete space is pseudocomplete, that every pseudocomplete space is Baire, and that every product of pseudocomplete spaces is pseudocomplete.

In the proof of the last fact there is a small issue for me, but first the definitions:

- A topological space is *quasiregular* if every nonempty open set contains the closure of a nonempty open set.

  A family of nonempty open sets $\mathcal{B}$ is called a *π-base* (or *pseudobase*, but this name collides with the notion of pseudobase related to *pseudocharacter*) if every nonempty open set contains a member of $\mathcal{B}$.

  A topological space is *pseudocomplete* if it is quasiregular and there exist a sequence $\{\mathcal{B}_n: n ∈ ω\}$ of π-bases such that every sequence $B_0 ⊇ \overline{B_1} ⊇ B_1 ⊇ \overline{B_2} ⊇ B_2 ⊇ \cdots$ such that each $B_n ∈ \mathcal{B}_n$ has nonempty intersection.

In the proof of the productivity of pseudocomplete spaces it is needed that even sequences $B_{n_0} ⊇ \overline{B_{n_0 + 1}} ⊇ B_{n_0 + 1} ⊇ \overline{B_{n_0 + 2}} ⊇ B_{n_0 + 2} ⊇ \cdots$ where $B_n ∈ \mathcal{B}_n$ for $n ≥ n_0$ have nonempty intersection (i.e. we may start later in the sequence of $π$-bases). Oxtoby says that we may assume that $X$ is in every $\mathcal{B}_n$, but I do not see why it is the case. It seems that simply adding $X$ to the π-bases may destroy the property of the sequence. On the other hand, what seems to work is to remove some members of the π-bases. Namely, we put $\mathcal{B}'_0 := \mathcal{B}_0$ and $\mathcal{B}'_{n + 1} := \{B ∈ \mathcal{B}_{n + 1}: ∃C ∈ \mathcal{B}'_n: \overline{B} ⊆ C\}$. These will still be π-bases and for every $B_{n_0} ∈ \mathcal{B}'_{n_0}$ there is $B_{n_0 -1} ∈ \mathcal{B}'_{n_0 - 1}$ such that $B_{n_0 - 1} ⊇ \overline{B_{n_0}} ⊇ B_{n_0}$ and so on, i.e. we may extend the sequence at the beginning. This modified sequence satisfies the property we need and we may even add $X$ to these π-bases (unless $X = ∅$). But the argument seems to be nontrivial for a comment like “we may assume that $X ∈ \mathcal{B}_n$”. So I wonder, am I missing something?

**Updated:** Let me give a concrete example of the situation. Let's write $U \prec V$ for $\overline{U} ⊆ V$. Let $\{\mathcal{B}_n: n ∈ ω\}$ be a pseudocompleteness-witnessing sequence for $(0, 1)$ such that every member of $\mathcal{B}_n$ has diameter $< 2^{-(n + 2)}$, let $A_n := (0, 2^{-n})$, and let $\mathcal{B}'_n := \mathcal{B}_n ∪ \{A_n\}$.

The sequence $\mathcal{B}_0, \mathcal{B}'_1, \mathcal{B}'_2, …$ still witnesses that $(0, 1)$ is pseudocomplete since every compatible $\prec$-decreasing sequence $\{B_n: n ∈ ω\}$ is in fact compactible with the original system $\{\mathcal{B}_n: n ∈ ω\}$: if $B_{n + 1} = A_{n + 1}$, then $B_n = A_n$ since $A_n$ is the only member of $B'_n$ containing $A_{n + 1}$, but $A_0 = X ∉ \mathcal{B}_0$. On the other hand, if we add $X$ to $\mathcal{B}_0$, i.e. if we consider the system $\{\mathcal{B}'_n: n ∈ ω\}$, then we have the compatible sequence $A_0 \succ A_1 \succ A_2 \succ \cdots$ with empty intersection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$Your example shows that we cannot simply add $X$ to each of the $\pi$-bases, but only because the sets $A_n$ ($n\ge 1$) are basically irrelevant: they cannot appear in any sequence

$$B_0\supseteq\cl B_1\supseteq B_1\supseteq\cl B_2\supseteq B_2\supseteq\ldots$$

**until** $X=A_0$ is added to $\mathscr{B}_0$.

However, a simple preliminary step makes it possible to ensure that $X$ is in each $\pi$-base. Suppose that $\{\mathscr{B}_n:n\in\omega\}$ is a family of $\pi$-bases witnessing the pseudocompleteness of $X$. Let $\mathscr{B}_0'=\mathscr{B}_0$, and for $n\in\omega$ let

$$\mathscr{B}_{n+1}'=\{B\in\mathscr{B}_{n+1}:\exists U\in\mathscr{B}_n'\,(\cl B\subseteq U)\}\,.$$

Each $\mathscr{B}_n'$ is still a $\pi$-base for $X$, so $\{\mathscr{B}_n':n\in\omega\}$ still witnesses the pseudocompleteness of $X$, and it’s easy to see that $\{\mathscr{B}_n\cup\{X\}:n\in\omega\}$ also witnesses the pseudocompleteness of $X$.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. It just seemed not trivial enough for the comment “we may assume that $X∈\mathcal{B}_n$” from the original paper.

Comment: @user87690: For what it’s worth, it’s far from being the largest jump that I’ve seen silently left to the reader. That’s the only paper of Oxtoby’s (as distinct from his book) that I’ve read, so I don’t have a feel for his normal level of detail.

Answer (score 2):

It's really quite trivial that $X$ can be added to every pseudobase sequence of $\pi$-bases $\{\mathcal{B}_n: n \in \omega \}$ that witnesses pseudocompleteness. "It seems that simply adding $X$ to the $\pi$-bases may destroy the property of the sequence" as you say. I don't see that at all:

Suppose we add $X$ to all of them (of course keeps them all a $\pi$-base) and we'd suddenly have a counterexample to pseudocompleteness: a sequence $B_n \in \mathcal{B}_n, n \in \omega$ with $\forall n \in \omega: B_n \supseteq \overline{B_{n+1}}$ and such that $\bigcap_n B_n = \emptyset$. This means that we must have had $B_n = X$ infinitely many times (otherwise we could have started the sequence after the last occurrence of $X$, the only new set we added, and we cannot have $B_n \neq X$ for all $n$, because the original subbases do not have such a sequence) but then the decreasingness forces *all* $B_n = X$ and then the intersection is definitely not empty, but $X$. So we cannot add a bad sequence by adding $X$ to all $\pi$-bases, but it *is* convenient, because we then can use standard product base elements formed from the subbases to get the subbase for the product.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't see it. Suppose I give you a sequence $X \succ X \succ B_2 \succ B_3 \succ \cdots$ satisfying the conditions. How do I know that it has nonempty intersection? It does not follow from the defining condition of pseudocompletenes – to apply the condition we would need to provide sets $B_0$ and $B_1$ from the original π-bases compatible with the given sequence, but that may not be possible.

Comment: @user87690 We could just take all $\pi$-bases from $ n \ge 2$ as witnessing instead.. Note that any infinite subsequence of the $\pi$-bases that witness pseudocompleteness also witnesses pseudocompleteness!

Comment: That's the issue, that's what I don't see at all. According to the definition there should be a sequence of π-bases that works for all chains starting at $0$ for that base. I don't see why it should work also for chains starting at $n_0$ or equivalently why each infinite subsequence of the π-bases witnesses pseudocompleteness as well.

Comment: I have added an example showing that adding $X$ to the π-bases may break the desired property.

Comment: @user87690 you cannot add the $ A_n$ to the subbases I think. They only sets with compact closures should be in it.

Comment: Why? It is not required by the definition of pseudocompleteness. Or do you mean that my claim that $\mathcal{B}_0, \mathcal{B}'_1, \mathcal{B}'_2, …$ is a pseudo-complete sequence is incorrect?

Comment: I'm sorry, there has to be some misunderstanding. If by the original sequence you mean $\mathcal{B}_0, \mathcal{B}_1, …$, then it is witnessing pseudocompleteness by definition – surely $(0, 1)$ is pseudocomplete and surely this may be witnessed by a sequence satisfying my conditions on diameters, so I just took one such sequence.

Comment: @user87690 The argument you gave for $\mathcal{B}_0, \mathcal{B}'_1, \mathcal{B}'_2,\ldots$ being a witnessing sequence is incorrect, I believe.

Comment: I do not see any gap in the proof. Or maybe the whole point is how I interpret the definition – to me the enumeration of the sequence of the π-bases is fixed and the defining condition relies on this fixed enumeration.